# Is it possible to deselect all values in a RadioButton Group?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have a form in an ASP.NET MVC site which the user can edit and return to at a later time.

If they accidentally select a value in a radio button group, is there any way to make it unselected?

By default, once it's clicked, it can't be unclicked!

Comment: Why the rollback? This question is not necessarily related to ASP.NET nor ASP.NET MVC 3. At least tag it as html. When you say 'make it unselectable' that carries a different meaning than 'deselected'.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was rolling back one of my own edits...

Comment: OK, I was hoping it wasn't something you didn't like about what I did ;)

Comment: Not at all - just been at the laptop a bit too long! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with plain [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). Example:

```js
function clearRadios(groupName) {
  var r = document.getElementsByName(groupName);
  for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    r[i].checked = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="myGroup">A</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myGroup">B</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myGroup">C</label>
<button type="button" onclick="clearRadios('myGroup')">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Does this work after I select A and post back? ...Because she said .NET... And your answer doesn't sound frustrated and pissed at Microsoft...

Comment: LOL! If your inputs are `runat="server"` I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, create another radio button labelled "None" or something appropriate to your form that's part of the same 'group' then they can select that instead.

But in reality, if you need them to be able to deselect then you need a checkbox and not a radio button.

Comment: Thanks, I unfortunately thought that'd be the case.  The problem is, there is only one selection allowed, so checkboxes are inappropriate. And we can't add another field as this would imply that "None" is a valid option.  It the fact that the form is in progress that makes a non-selection valid...

Comment: If the user must select one of the options *before* submitting the form then why would they want to deselect? They just go back an select a different option.

Comment: That is what I thought they would do - but it's come back as a UAT issue... :)